# Firefox Only CSS in a Media Query

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write some css that will only work in firefox, that is within a media query so it only works after 767px. Below is what I've currently written but it doesn't work.

```
@media only (min-width: 767px) {
    @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
       .SearchBlock input {
           width:88% !important;
       }
    }
}
```

It works just fine without the "@media only" section, but I only want it to work after 767px. Is this possible?

Edit: Changed resolution to width.

Comment: `only screen and (min-width: 767px)` instead of `min-resolution`

Comment: That didn't work. Although I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... In your question you say you need it to work "after 767px". I read this as you need it to work from 767px and higher. In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958589/firefox-only-css-in-a-media-query#comment80864980_46958657) however, you need it to work "below 767px" which I read as 767px and less.

Comment: @MartinHomola He gets notifications when you supply an answer. No need to post a comment about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `min-resolution`. Use

**`min-width`**: if you need to apply CSS to the devices which are more than 767px, and use

**`max-width`**: If you need to apply CSS to the devices having size less than 767px - for mobiles

**Example:**

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
       .SearchBlock input {
           width:88% !important;
       }
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @salwine How come? Can you post the full code here?

Comment: I copied your code exactly and it didn't work. As I said in the post, without the @media screen and (min-width:767px), the code works fine. But I don't want it to work on all resolution. I just need it to work below 767px in width.

Comment: @salwine So then use `max-width` instead of `min-width`

Comment: Its my pleasure @salwine

Answer (score 0):

Change `min-resolution` to `min-width`.

Resolution is for the pixel density of the device. `width` refers to the actual width which is what you want.

The url-prefix portion needs to have the url of the document the style rules refer to, such as

`url-prefix("https://example.com/")`

> The @document CSS at-rule restricts the style rules contained within
>   it based on the URL of the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake on my part. Still isn't working, though.

Comment: @salwine Don't you need to provide a value for `url-prefix()`?

Comment: @salwine There is something missing from what you've given us that is affecting this. The CSS works as I show, even without the url.

Comment: @salwine Do `@media screen **and**` and see if it works.

Comment: `url-prefix("https://example.com/")` is not working. It has to be empty - `url-prefix()`.

Comment: @MartinHomola MDN says it must be filled. The purpose is to list a URL. However, it works for me without one, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the result because you are using min-resolution correctly.

You can do one of the 2 :

1. Either change min-resolution to min-width
2. Enter resolution value in min-resolution for example min-resolution(192dpi)

Px is not the unit of resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Should work! :)

```css
 .SearchBlock input {
   display: block;
   width: 30%;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
      .SearchBlock input {
           width:88% !important;
       }
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="SearchBlock">
 <input type="text" placeholder="text"/> 
</div>
```